# How can I incrementally add a number to a selected class in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am dynamically generating content using Drupal. I am running javascript that places a div before another div. The code works fine, and looks like this:

```
  $(function() {
    $('.views-row-1 .content .body').insertBefore('.views-row-1 .content .field-name-field-image-one');

   });
```

My issue is that because the content is generated dynamically, the class "views-row-#" changes incrementally. For example, if I have 3 elements of content on the page, Drupal will create the class  views-row-1 for the first one, views-row-2 for the second, views-row-3 for the third.

What I have done (which is not ideal) is written out a line of code for each piece of content like so:

```
  $(function() {
    $('.views-row-1 .content .body').insertBefore('.views-row-1 .content .field-name-field-image-one'); // check before() examples
    $('.views-row-2 .content .body').insertBefore('.views-row-2 .content .field-name-field-image-one'); // check before() examples
    $('.views-row-3 .content .body').insertBefore('.views-row-3 .content .field-name-field-image-one'); // check before() examples
    $('.views-row-4 .content .body').insertBefore('.views-row-4 .content .field-name-field-image-one') 
   });
```

I will never know how many pieces of content there will be because it's dynamic, so I'm looking to have the javascript add the number to the class. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('[class^="views-row"]').each(function(){

    var className = //get classname to insert before 
   //not sure if .index() will help you since you have not posted your HTML

   $(this).find('.content .body').insertBefore(className);
});
```

Comment: Here's a possible implementation for this solution, I removed the `.` in the selector since it didn't work with it. http://jsfiddle.net/bM4GK/2/

Answer (score 0):

Add a specific class for each of the rows, let's call it 'divAppend' here.

Then do:

```
$('.divAppend').each(function() {
    $(this).insertBefore('whateveryouareinserting');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
function iterate () {
    var view = null;
    var i = 1;
    while ((view = $('.views-row-' + i + ' .content .body')).size() > 0) {
        alert(view.text());
        view.insertBefore('.views-row-' + i + ' .content .field-name-field-image-one');
        i++;
    }    
}
$(function() {
    iterate();
});
​
```

It works although it's not pretty at all. Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bM4GK/) for it.
    ​

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this, since Drupal also creates the class "view-row" for each piece of content. Thanks for all the help though, a lot of creative and useful solutions!

```
$('.views-row').each(function(i,e) {
  $('.content .body', e).insertBefore($('.content .field-name-field-image-one', e));
});
```